# Cannot understend net.TCPConn CloseWrite and CloseRead

Tags: go, tcp

Maybe it's simple, but i can't understand it. I have been reading go programing language book and one of exercise is

> In netcat3, the interface value conn has the concrete type
> *net.TCPConn, which represents a TCP connection. A TCP connection consists
> of two halves that may be closed independently using its CloseRead and
> CloseWrite methods. Modify the main goroutine of netcat3 to close only the
> write half of the connection so that the program will continue to print the final echoes
> from the reverb1 server even after the standard input has been closed.

And i stuck on it. I have to use simple tcp server from https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch8/reverb2/reverb.go

and needs to modify client
https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch8/netcat3/netcat.go

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

//!+
func main() {
    //conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    tcpAdr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAdr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    done := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        _, e := io.Copy(os.Stdout, conn) // NOTE: ignoring errors
        log.Println("done", e)
        done <- struct{}{} // signal the main goroutine
    }()
    mustCopy(conn, os.Stdin)
    conn.CloseWrite()
    <-done // wait for background goroutine to finish
    conn.CloseRead()
}

//!-

func mustCopy(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader) {
    if _, err := io.Copy(dst, src); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

And the problem:

Why, if i call conn.CloseWrite() after mustCopy() succesfuly end, io.Copy in anonymous function gorutine is also ended and process finished with no errors? Server side is saying:

> write tcp 127.0.0.1:8000->127.0.0.1:58797: use of closed network connection

like i'm using conn.Close(). In my opinion conn.CloseWrite() should't block read side. After severlal hours of googling, i found that after syscallShotdown(SHUT_WR) call, the connection is sending something called FIN

> If the TCP stack receives a shutdown with SHUT_WR only, it shall mark this connection as no more data can be sent. All pending write requests will be finished, but subsequent write requests will fail. **Furthermore, a FIN packet will be sent to another side to inform them we don't have more data to send.**

Is it my problem? Client closes write connection -> send FIN -> server in response to FIN send FIN to host -> client read connection takes FIN and close connection from it's side?

I have no any advanced knowledge about how sockets or connections are working. I love digging in source code but those file descriptors and other things now is too hard for me. And sorry for bad english:)

Comment: "Client closes write connection -> send FIN -> server in response to FIN send FIN to host -> client read connection takes FIN and close connection from it's side?": yes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the server side.

```golang
func handleConn(c net.Conn) {
    input := bufio.NewScanner(c)
    for input.Scan() {
        go echo(c, input.Text(), 1*time.Second)
    }
    // NOTE: ignoring potential errors from input.Err()
    c.Close()
}
```

After receiving `FIN` (caused by client's `SHUT_WR`), server's `input.Scan()` loop is interrupted, and it is a correct behaviour because it is no reason to continue reading when writer (client) has notified that it has no more data to write.

After that `c.Close()` immediately closes connection, and it is a mistake because at the same time writing goroutine(s) `go echo(c, input.Text(), 1*time.Second)` uses that connection and get error `use of closed network connection`. So server itself closes connection for its goroutine. To fix that, server should close connection only after writing goroutine(s) completes its work.

Fix may looks like:

```golang
func handleConn(c net.Conn) {
    input := bufio.NewScanner(c)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for input.Scan() {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(text string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            echo(c, text, 1*time.Second)
        }(input.Text())
    }
    // NOTE: ignoring potential errors from input.Err()
    wg.Wait()
    c.Close()
}
```

Or just remove concurrency within single connection:

```golang
func handleConn(c net.Conn) {
    input := bufio.NewScanner(c)
    for input.Scan() {
        echo(c, input.Text(), 1*time.Second)
    }
    // NOTE: ignoring potential errors from input.Err()
    c.Close()
}
```

P.S. My experiments related to that question you can find [here](https://github.com/e-zhydzetski/go-experiments/tree/master/tcpclose).